# Retrieving strings from ontology in OWL format

Tags: string, extract, ontology, owlready

I have an ontology of the human anatomy in OWL format which I want to import using owlready in python 3. I want to retrieve the labels and descriptions of the organs within the ontology so I can compare them to those of a different ontology. I tried this:

```
for c in onto.classes():
    print(ANNOTATIONS[c]["label"])
```

But it says:

> `name 'ANNOTATIONS' is not defined.`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out owlready doesn't recognize OWL/RDF format, only OWL/XML. Going to try ontospy instead